# Trouble with plotting a probability density function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

new to MATLAB, I made a function that takes a vector of data, normalizes it, plots the histogram and overlays a probability density function on it. The problem is that the PDF seems to have multiple lines instead of one smooth curve. A little hard to explain so I'll post a picture. I've made many changes to the code I have below but nothing seems to plot a single smooth curve PDF. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
function hist_gauss(x)
y = ~isnan(x);
data = x(y);
mdata = mean(data);
sdata = std(data);
Pf = (1/(sdata*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp((-(data - mdata).^2)/(2*sdata.^2));
[p,q] = hist(data,100);
delta_x = q(2)-q(1);
a = sum(p)*delta_x;
bar(q, (p/sum(p))/(delta_x));hold on
plot(data, Pf, 'r'); hold off
```

[image: Function Output with sample data]

Comment: Presumably because `x` is not monotonically increasing.

Comment: Yes, use `sort` to sort `x`.

Comment: @horchler consider answering the question, for the shake of giving it closure.